# enable Write-Verbose behavior in powershell script

Tags: powershell

In a powershell script `file.ps1`, I have

```powershell
Write-Host "here is a host message"
Write-Verbose "here is a verbose message"
```

When `file.ps1` is run in Windows Terminal using Powershell 7, not all messages are written to the console.

```text
PS> .\file.ps1
here is a host message
```

I would like to be able to pass `-Verbose` so `Write-Verbose` is seen:

```text
PS> .\file.ps1 -Verbose
here is a host message
here is a verbose message
```

What does script `file.ps1` need to enable verbose messages?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to add [`[cmdletbinding()]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_cmdletbindingattribute?view=powershell-7.2) to your script to enable [**CommonParameters**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.2#:%7E:text=The%20common%20parameters%20are%20a,an%20effect%20on%20all%20cmdlets.):

**script.ps1**

```
[cmdletbinding()]
param()

Write-Host "here is a host message"
Write-Verbose "here is a verbose message"
```

From host:

```
PS /> ./script.ps1 -Verbose

here is a host message
VERBOSE: here is a verbose message
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't edit the script, you can also user set the VerbosePrefrence to Continue in the shell that calls the script.

```
$VerbosePreference = "Continue"
```

This will enable Verbose output on all function you are goint to execute.
Check out [Microsofts Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.2#verbosepreference) about Prefences.
There are many usefull more.

If you ike to enable Verbose Output for only a specific CmdLet, you can use $PSDefaultParameterValues to assign a default Parameter to this function:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues.Add("MyCmdLet:Verbose",$true)
```

this would enable Verbose Output for "MyCmdLet".
However, be carefull when using $PSDefaultParameterValues, since you can really mess things up, especially if you call other script, since the default parameter values will there be affected aswell.